# Second list item should gets selected

Tags: jquery

Please refer following snippet :

```
<ul class="form-picker radio" id="select-template-type">
    <li value="1" class="use-template-type selected">Use Template</li>
    <li value="2" class="custom-template-type">Custom Violation</li>
    <input type="hidden" id="template_type_id" name="" value="">
</ul>
```

I want to apply class `selected` to the second `li` on the form load but it fails. This is what I tried:

```
$( '#select-template-type').eq(2).addClass('selected');
```

After clicking I need to trigger that `li` as well.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the selected `li`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_nth-child.asp)

```js
$(function(){

  $("ul.form-picker li").removeClass("selected");
  $("ul.form-picker li:nth-child(2)").addClass("selected");

});
```

```css
.selected
{
 border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="form-picker radio" id="select-template-type">
                <li value="1" class="use-template-type selected">Use Template</li>
                <li value="2" class="custom-template-type">Custom Violation</li>
                <input type="hidden" id="template_type_id" name="" value="">
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do it,

`$('#select-template-type').children().eq(1).addClass("selected")`

OR

`$('#select-template-type li:eq(1)').addClass("selected")`